# PHP iterate through nested array encoded to array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Im trying to do a foreach loop to get all the `value` in an array & another loop for `addresses`.

My code:

```php
$json = json_decode($response, true);
foreach($json["result"]["vout"]["value"] as $a)
{
    echo "<br> $a";
}
```

```json
{
    "result": {
        "vout": [
            {
                "value": 0.09998700,
                "n": 0,
                "scriptPubKey": {
                    "addresses": [
                        "16Tjr2hz67mQW1YHpSLnKKDoXi4na6D66W"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "value": 1.63707231,
                "n": 1,
                "scriptPubKey": {
                    "addresses": [
                        "1LSnED1PUpssw9JAa2PPsypmjKrnMfz6u3"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "value": 5.00000000,
                "n": 2,
                "scriptPubKey": {
                    "addresses": [
                        "17BkwbuiiDqMQGqBomZeR2XUmKzhv8EwDg"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "confirmations": 2885,
        "time": 1620396315,
        "blocktime": 1620396315
    },
    "error": null,
    "id": "curltest"
}
```

Error:

```
Warning: Undefined array key "value" in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 27
Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 27
```

Small information:
`$response` is a json object i get from a curl
`$json` is the json formatted in the standard php array structure

Comment: `$json["result"]["vout"]["value"]` doesn't exist because vout is an array

Comment: Why should it not be possible?

Comment: You could loop through `$json["result"]["vout"]` and then get the value from each item in that array...

Comment: Still shoots out an error Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 27

even though i tried echo strval

Comment: Show exactly how you changed the code, please

Comment: With `$json["result"]["vout"]` -> `print_r($a["scriptPubKey"]["addresses"]);`

Comment: Well addresses is an array so you can't print it directly

Answer (score 2):

There is some issue with your code as `$json["result"]["vout"]["value"]` does not exist.

So, you need to loop through over `$json["result"]["vout"]`

as below:

```
foreach($json["result"]["vout"] as $a)
{
    $value = $a['value'];
    echo "<br> $value";
}
```